# UltraVNC Single Click, unable to connect due to security issues

Tags: certificate, vnc, vnc-server, java-security

I'm currently trying to install and configure Ultra VNC Single Click. I managed to run VNC SC after creating an ultra vnc ini file (http://blog.jorisvisscher.com/2013/07/05/run-ultravnc-as-user-prevent-no-password/).

If I try to connect via browser (`http://<ip>:5805/`) I get the following exception: "Certificate has been revoked. The application will not be executed" (See: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64269444/stackoverflow/ApplicationRevoked.png)

To get rid of it the following configuration can be done: 
"System Preferences / Java / Advanced /"
"Perform signed code certificate recovation checks on" = "Do not check".

This is now "solved" and another issue occures: "Application blocked by Java Security" (see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64269444/stackoverflow/ApplicationBlocked.png)

I can get rid of it by:
* "System Preferences / Java / Security /" 
* adding `http://<ip>:5805/` as an exception site

Disabling/Circumventing security settings is not the solution I'm looking for. How can I solve both issues?

An addition, which is quite strange: 
The winvnc.exe certificate is valid until 12.10.2016. If I try to connect, get the error message, click "more information" and "view certificate details", the validity of "uvnc bvba" is set to "18.03.2014". This might cause the issue. I don't get, why the certificate date is different...

My setup:
* VNC SC installed on Win7
* trying to connect from Mac 10.10.1, with Java 8

Thanks for your help!